# CredSSP Encryption Oracle Remediation Error

Tags: azure

Hello we are using Azure Virtural Machine. Now We cannot remote into the server due to the following error message. Would like to get suggestion on the error since we don't have the support plan and the live agent suggest me to ask here.

Thanks all.

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43dZB.png)

Comment: OMG!. The same issue im facing right now. Exactly before 24HR i logged in to my VM but unable to do that right now. :( Let me know if you resolved this issue. Im also searching

Comment: I have also just ran into this issue...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I resolved the issue temporarily. Follow these steps on your **local computer (not on server)**

> Note : The below steps are not recommended by Microsoft. So follow these steps just to login to your machine and do necessary updates. Once it's done, revert the configuration changes

1 . Go to "Administrative Templates" (type /search it directly on window)

2. [image]

Please see above image.

3. Right click and edit Encryption Oracle Remediation.
4. Make it enabled, and change protection level to "vulnerable"
5. Click on Apply and close window.
6. Try to connect to VM. And after establishing a connection, update the VM if there's any pending updates

Comment: Thanks. I followed the steps and now it is ok. But My colleague didn't do anything but she can remote into server with no issue anymore. May be Microsoft itself updates something again to solve this issue.

Comment: I have face same issue, but unable to view Administrative Templates. Any other way to achieve this solution. I have used windows 10 Home single language OS.

Comment: @MaulikKakadiya try adding this rgistry

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters] "AllowEncryptionOracle"=dword:00000002

Comment: Try to restart your system before viewing Administrative templates @Maulik Kakadiya. Mine worked.

Comment: i cant figure out how to open "Local Group Policy Editor". gpedit.msc is not found in system32

Comment: @MIKE if you are unable to do so, try adding/editing registry key directly as i specified in above comment

Answer (score 2):

For a fast workaround that doesn't involve any server side changes just type the following in a console with administrator privileges

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters" /f /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2
```

I didn't have permission (human permission) to make any change to the server so this was a perfect solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution for me was to download remote desktop app on my phone and connect to remote server. Install windows updates on remote server and I was able to connect again from my pc

Answer (score 1):

Login into https://portal.azure.com
Navigate to the Azure Virtual Machine tab and go to the VM that is giving this error
Now under operations, select the Run Command option which will give you the option to run a PowerShell script

In the PowerShell script section, type in the below two lines and click on run
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters\ /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters' -name "AllowEncryptionOracle" 2 -Type DWord

Now on your own machine (client machine), follow the below steps:

On the client that has the CredSSP update installed, run gpedit.msc, and then browse to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation in the navigation pane.

Change the Encryption Oracle Remediation policy to Enabled, and then change Protection Level to Vulnerable.

If needed, please restart the server and now when you try to RDP into your Azure VM you will be able to login and complete the connection. Please note that it is highly recommended to patch your VMs and follow the latest guidelines that are mentioned in the [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4295591/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-to-rdp-to-azure-vm) or [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rohit-minni/2018/06/12/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-rdp-to-a-windows-vm-in-azure/)

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved, just use this below command 
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters" /f /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My server didn't have the option.

> Encryption Oracle Remediation

But I solved it by unchecking

> Allow connections only from computers with network level authentication

under system properties as shown in figure.

[image: RDP with unchecking network level authentication]